# is there any difference between matmul and usual multiplication of tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I am confused between the multiplication between two tensors using * and matmul.
Below is my code

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(7)
features = torch.randn((2, 5))
weights = torch.randn_like(features)
```

here, i want to multiply weights and features. so, one way to do it is as follows

```
print(torch.sum(features * weights))
```

Output:

```
tensor(-2.6123)
```

Another way to do is using matmul

```
print(torch.mm(features,weights.view((5,2))))
```

but, here output is

```
tensor([[ 2.8089,  4.6439],
        [-2.3988, -1.9238]])
```

What i don't understand here is that why `matmul` and usual multiplication are giving different outputs, when both are same. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Edit: When, i am using feature of shape `(1,5)` both * and `matmul` outputs are same. 
but, its not the same when the shape is `(2,5)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `*`, the multiplication is elementwise, when you use `torch.mm` it is matrix multiplication.

Example:

```
a = torch.rand(2,5)
b = torch.rand(2,5)
result = a*b
```

`result` will be shaped the same as `a` or `b` i.e `(2,5)`
whereas considering operation

```
result = torch.mm(a,b)
```

It will give a size mismatch error, as this is proper matrix multiplication (as we study in linear algebra) and `a.shape[1] != b.shape[0]`. When you apply the view operation in `torch.mm` you are trying to match the dimensions.

In the special case of the shape in some particular dimension being 1, it becomes a dot product and hence `sum (a*b)` is same as `mm(a, b.view(5,1))`